# Tkinter program runs perfectly on Windows but lags on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Im making a synthasia type program that allows you to upload a midi file and shows you the notes live on the keyboard. However, the program freezes at random points when I try to run it on my Macbook, until I shake my mouse around or click on the tkinter window to "wake it up". However, this problem is not prevelant at all when I run my program on windows. Does anybody have any idea why that is?

Here is my code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import threading
mid = mido.MidiFile('test.midi')
msg=[]
for i, track in enumerate(mid.tracks):
     for mess in track:
       if mess.type=='note_on' or mess.type=='note_off':
         msg.append(mess)

for i in msg:
  print(i)
x=0
key=[]

keys_on={
}
notes_on={
}
notes_off=[]
refresh=0.1
def onKeyRelease(event):
  print('You released')
  print(event.char)
  keyboard.itemconfig(key[26]["obj"], fill='white')
  key[26]["pressed"]=False
def onKeyPress(event):
    print('You pressed')
    print(event.char)
    keyboard.itemconfig(key[26]["obj"], fill='red')
    key[26]["pressed"]=True

def draw():
#creates rectangle for each message in midi file
  count=0
  for i in msg:
    
    anim((i.time/960)*(1/refresh))
    if count==14:
      print("thing")
    if len(notes_off)==7:
      print("thing")
    if count==15:
      print("thing")
    if i.type=='note_on':
      
      x1,y1,x2,y2=keyboard.coords(key[i.note-36]["obj"])
      rec = canvas.create_rectangle(
    x1,0,x2,0,
    outline="black",
    fill="green")
      notes_on[i.note]=rec
    else:
      info={}
      info["object"]=notes_on[i.note]
      info["note"]=i.note
      notes_off.append(info)
      del notes_on[i.note]
    count+=1
  while True:
    anim(1)
def anim(loop):
# animates rectangles to move downwards
    for j in range(int(loop)):
      for i in notes_on:
        x1,y1,x2,y2=canvas.coords(notes_on[i])
      
        canvas.coords(notes_on[i],x1,y1,x2,y2+3)
      for j in notes_off:
        canvas.move(j["object"],0,3)
        x1,y1,x2,y2=canvas.coords(j["object"])
        if y2>=300:
          if j["note"] not in keys_on: 
            keys_on[j["note"]]="on"
        if y1>=300:
          del keys_on[j["note"]]
          del j
      check()
      ws.update()
      time.sleep(refresh)
def check():
#check if correct keys pressed
  for i in keys_on:
    while not key[i-36]["pressed"]:

      time.sleep(0.1)



      



ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
SCREEN_WIDTH=500
ws.geometry('500x360')
ws.config(bg='red')
ws.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
ws.bind('<KeyRelease>',onKeyRelease)


canvas = Canvas(
    ws,
    height=300,
    width=SCREEN_WIDTH,
    bg="#fff",
    #bd=-2,
    highlightthickness=0
    )
    
canvas.pack(expand=True)

keyboard = Canvas(
    ws,
    height=60,
    width=SCREEN_WIDTH,
    bg="#fff",
    bd=0,
    highlightthickness=0
    )

keyboard.pack(side=BOTTOM)
def white():
  global x

  rec = keyboard.create_rectangle(
    x, 0, x+20, 50,
    outline="black",
    fill="white")
  info={}
  info["pressed"]=False
  info["obj"]=rec
  key.append(info)
  x=x+20


def black():
  global x
  
  t=keyboard.create_rectangle(
    memx-5,0,memx+5,30,
    outline="black",
    fill="black")
  info={}
  info["pressed"]=False
  info["obj"]=t
  length = len(key)
  key.insert(length-1,info)
  

# drawing piano keys
while x<SCREEN_WIDTH-30 :

  white()
  memx=x
  
  white()
  black()
  memx=x
  white()
  black()
  white()
  memx=x
  white()
  black()
  memx=x
  white()
  black()
  memx=x
  white()
  black()
  memx=x

t1=threading.Thread(target=draw)
t1.start()




ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see some `while True:` in code - and maybe it blocks `mainloop` so it can't update widgets in window.

Comment: first you could clean code to make it more readable. You could put all function directly after `imports`. And use spaces around `=`, and space afer `,`, and empty line before `def`, and indentations with 4 spaces. More in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)